# How can I disable the "Challenge" event in ASP.NET Core's `JwtBearerDefaults` scheme?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I'm using the JwtBearer scheme in my ASP.NET Core application.

`services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`

However, this results in a challenge, which I do not want.  Is there an easy way to disable/prevent/handle the challenge so that it does not execute, without abandoning the entire middleware?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can disable/handle `Challenge`, as well as other events such as `TokenValidated`, `MessageReceived`, and `AuthenticationFailed` by setting the `Events` property of the `JwtBearerOptions` and providing your own methods, as seen below:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            #region Custom Code Added Here
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters();
                    //Override the JWT Events
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnChallenge = context =>
                        {
                            //custom logic goes here.  At the end of your logic make sure that you
                            //"Handle" the response by calling HandleResponse, and return a 0.
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
                });
            #endregion
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```